# Pyinstaller usage within python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Can't really find an answer in the Doc / google.

Is it possible to use pyinstaller to generate build withing the python script? or the only right option is to execute command line command by `subprocess` module, ex:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, run,

run(['pyinstaller', '--onefile', 'file.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, timeout=20)
```

pseudo-code for what i want to do:

```
from pyinstaller import PyInstaller

build = PyInstaller.build('file.py', onefile=true, distpath=*path*, workpath=*path*)
file_path = build.get_path()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research for you, so: it's unnecessarily hard to do it, but there is solution: module [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), which can be called directly in the code. Here's a tutorial which can teach you few useful things: [How to use cx_freeze](https://youtu.be/HosXxXE24hA)